# How to scrape a huge amounts of tweets

Tags: python, twitter, screen-scraping

I am building a project in python that needs to scrape huge and huge amounts of Twitter data. Something like 1 million users and all their tweets need to be scraped.

Previously I have used Tweepy and Twython, but hit the limit of Twitter very fast.

How do sentiment analysis companies etc. get their data? How do they get all those tweets? Do you buy this somewhere or build something that iterates through different proxies or something?

How do companies like Infochimps with for example Trst rank get all their data? 
* http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/twitter-census-trst-rank

Comment: If you hit the limit too fast, then you should distribute your work among many days, and build your database more slowly. I think that's how the companies do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the *latest* tweets from specific users, Twitter offers the [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api).

> The Streaming API is the real-time sample of the Twitter Firehose. This API is for those developers with data intensive needs. If you're looking to build a **data mining product** or are interested in **analytics research**, the Streaming API is most suited for such things.

If you're trying to access *old* information, the REST API with its severe request limits is the only way to go.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this will work for what you're trying to do, but the [Tweets2011](http://trec.nist.gov/data/tweets/) dataset was recently released.

From the description:

> As part of the TREC 2011 microblog track, Twitter provided identifiers
>   for approximately 16 million tweets sampled between January 23rd and
>   February 8th, 2011. The corpus is designed to be a reusable,
>   representative sample of the twittersphere - i.e. both important and
>   spam tweets are included.

Comment: thanks, that's an interesting one for me to look into. However, I want to be able to get the data of specific users in some way. Also preferable I want to be able to scrape the latest tweets from around 1 million users on a daily basis. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Pretty sure you won't be able to do that. The twitter API rate limits would throttle you too much.